# Propagate superclass methods up the chain defined in the superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a form library in which users can subclass my base form element and provide their own while also optionally providing subclasses of my `FormTheme` class to provide additional styling to those elements.

I have a property `themeClass` on the `FormElement` base class which the user can set to a custom theme class they've created. If they don't set it manually, I have this method:

```
- (Class)defaultThemeClass {
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    NSString *themeClassName = [className stringByAppendingString:@"Theme"];
    return NSClassFromString(themeClassName);
}
```

which just takes the element class name and appends `Theme` to it. (My library uses a naming convention in which an element class might be called `FormTableElement` and the corresponding cell and theme classes would be `FormTableCell` and `FormTableElementTheme`)

In my base form element class, I override the getter for `themeClass`

```
- (Class)themeClass {
    if(_themeClass) return _themeClass;
    Class defaultClass = [self defaultThemeClass];
    if(defaultClass) return defaultClass;
    else return NSClassFromString(@"FormElementTheme");
}
```

It's pretty simple, if the user has set a custom theme class it uses that, if not, it'll try to get the theme class based on the naming convention from `defaultThemeClass`. If those two fail, then the default theme class that's provided with the library is selected and all's good.

However, I ran into a situation I didn't anticipate where there's multiple levels of subclasses on the base form element like so:

```
FormElement
- FormTableRowElement
    - FormTableRowDetailElement
```

However there's only two concrete theme classes in play here, `FormElementTheme` and `FormTableRowElementTheme`. Furthermore, `FormTableRowDetailElement` uses properties of its superclass's theme element (which is `FormTableRowElementTheme`) but `themeClass only ever returns a custom class, the default class for that element, or the theme class for the superclass of all elements.

What I really need here is something like this:

```
- (Class)themeClass {
    if(_themeClass) return _themeClass;
    Class defaultClass = [self defaultThemeClass];
    if(defaultClass) return defaultClass;
    else if([super respondsToSelector:@selector(themeClass)]) {
        SEL themeSelector = @selector(themeClass);
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[super class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:themeSelector]];
        [invocation setSelector:themeSelector];
        invocation.target = super;
        [invocation invoke];
        Class returnValue;
        [invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
        return returnValue;  
    }
    else return NSClassFromString(@"FormElementTheme");
}
```

where if no theme element class exists for the element, it'll keep looking up the superclass chain until either the superclass doesn't respond to that method in which case it'll default to the base class theme or it does find an intermediary theme class and returns that.

The problem is of course that `super` is not an object but rather a keyword used by the compiler so you can't set the target of an `NSInvocation` to be `super`.

I need a way to achieve the same affect, propagating a method up the inheritance chain and it has to be defined in the base class because each subclass can't be responsible for either implementing this method or providing its own theme class (too much burden on the end user).

EDIT:

The other issue is that `FormElement` is a subclass of `NSObject` so any attempt to call `[super themeClass]` errors out.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can make something like this work:

```
class_respondsToSelector([self superclass], @selector(themeClass))
```

Note that `class_respondsToSelector` refers to instances of the class responding to the selector.

**EDIT:**

To call the super method you could:

```
static Class (*_method_invoke_class)(id, Method, ...) = (Class (*)(id, Method, ...)) method_invoke;

Method m = class_getInstanceMethod( [self superclass], @selector(themeClass) );
Class c = _method_invoke_class( self, m );
```

Comment: `[super respondsToSelector:@selector(themeClass)]` works fine but how do I call `themeClass` on `super` without using the `super` keyword?

Comment: You can query for the method implementation itself from the superclass and invoke it manually.  Answer updated with example.

Comment: That's a cool way of doing it, however it doesn't work, it just recursively calls the method on `self` not `super`